# Cannot create new Roles from the Roles Workspace

Tags: marketing-cloud, roles

i m trying to create a new role in our Marketing Cloud but when i go to Email-->Admin-->Roles
I have Administrator rights and MC Admin rights.
But cant see the button to create a new role. I never had this issue.
Is there anything i have to get activated from Salesforce?

[image: roles workspace]

Thank you
Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are not using an Enterprise Edition.

The Custom Roles and Permissions feature is included on Enterprise Editions. It's not available in the Basic Edition and is an optional extra (for an additional fee) on Pro and Corporate Editions. Refer to [this document](http://www2.sfdcstatic.com/assets/pdf/datasheets/mc_email_journey_pricing_sheet.pdf) for details on what features are included for each Edition.

If you are using an Enterprise Edition, check the user permissions that you have permission to create roles (this option will appear in the Permissions Workspace for all Editions, but will only be available on the Roles Workspace if you have an Enterprise Edition or have paid for this feature).

[image: role permissions]

Comment: HI Elliot,

thank you for the hints. Honestly i cant find the right person who is able to tell me whioch edition we are using :( 

Where in the Marceting Platform can i see what MC Edition iam currently using?

Thank you

Comment: I have the Admin profile but its under the Administrator "Role" "permissions" it says: Editing permissions has been disabled for this account.

How can i enable it?

Comment: @WernerHolm we are in a similar situation now. How did you end up enabling the editing permissions for the administrator role? Support ticket?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are in the Corporate edition and that is why you are unable to edit permission sets. But you can still control permissions for each user by going to My Users check the box next to their name and click on 'Manage Roles' then you see that there is a link for editing permissions that works as expected but for that specific user.